# Checkbox not displaying as it should on Thymeleaf

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I have a checkbox on my Thymeleaf(using Bootstrap) templates as it should. I have the following code to add a checkbox to my html templates:

```
     <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" th:value="${p.productId}">
    </td>
```

This is what I have when I run my application

[image]

When I click on a checkbox, I have the following

[image]

I do not have the normal check inside the square that we usually have. I have restarted my machine and cleared my cache several times, but I still have the same issue.

What could be the problem?

Comment: This should not be related with thymeleaf. I think you are having a style issue. Did you inspect the case by using browser developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="products" th:value="${p.productId}">[[${p.productId}]]
</td>
```

OR

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="products" th:value="${p.productId}">
<label>[[${p.productId}]]</label>
</td>
```